# WPFtoolkit Chart, Object Binding

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, charts

can anyone tell me whether I can bind an object with a brush (as a property) as a static property be bound as the background of a chart datapoint (to be specific column datapoint for the time being)? I am setting the itemsSource property with another data object. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

its just creating a binding to the background property the usual way:

```
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource mybackresource}, Path= myBackColor}"/>
```

mybackresource is the resource which is targeted at the class with the property myBackColor (the color we need a binding to).